# How does default constraint works in sql server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

In SQL server we can define default constraints in a table which fills a default value to a column on insert operation if no value is specified on the column. It works well.

But i want to know how it works. Does it works via an insert trigger to set the default value to the column or sql server detects the constraints and modifies the queries to set the default values?

If it works as explained in first case then at least two operations are needed to be done for a default constraint, which may be costly in many cases where multiple no of rows are inserted at a time and it will be better practice to specify the default values explicitly in the query like in cases with timestamps which can be easily passed to the query.

So, please explain how the default constraint works in SQL sever?

Comment: SQL Server has to neither create a trigger (and it wouldn't apply for `UPDATE` anyway) nor to modify queries - it just has an internal mechanism that deals with it. How closely that mechanism may *resemble* a trigger is neither here nor there. Remember, the facilities that are available to you as a T-SQL programmer are not necessarily the same facilities that are available to the people who *implement* SQL Server.

Comment: I suggest you do a performance test and generate stats for both cases. I would predict there would be no significant difference.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, i do believe same as all of us has been using it without raising question on it(not much info found about it in google). Just want to know how this is done.

I think since it affects only the new rows created, it can detect the newly rows inserted and fill the column values otherwise getting the specific entities from a set and update these would be costly. 

Lets see what others say on it :)

Comment: @Tanner, i was also thinking about it. Will give it a try in the weekend and update. You can also try and update us if possible.